# Comparing values of generic objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, comparison

I'm getting a problem, in my code, i made a loop retrieving the PropertyInfo of my object process and putting inside obj, but if my obj value was a List, I've to call another method, i'm trying to verify this using the following code, but my if block was not working.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo obj in process.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            email += createEmail(obj.Name, Convert.ToString(objeto.GetValue(processo, null)));

            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>))
            {
                CreateEmail<Object>(obj, "");
            }
        }
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well firstly, `obj.GetType()` will return type `PropertyInfo`; you actually want [obj.PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx). Even then, the type won't equal to the unbound `List<>` but rather some bound `List<T>` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (obj.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
    obj.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (System.Collections.Generic.List<>))
{

}
```